# Optimize query with count and index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-11

I have a table with more than 200,000,000 tuples and often I have to run the following query and show the result in a web page, which takes a long time:

```
select distinct(source), count(hitid) from tb_hit group by source;
```

I already created an index, but the query don't use it:

```
CREATE INDEX tb_hit_idx_5 on tb_hit USING btree (HitId ASC,Source ASC);
```

The Query Plan is here:

```
QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=10702925.57..10702925.62 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=330574.690..330574.705 rows=7 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=10702925.57..10702925.59 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=330574.689..330574.691 rows=7 loops=1)
         Sort Key: source, (count(hitid))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=10702919.26..10702925.50 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=330574.507..330574.647 rows=7 loops=1)
               Group Key: source
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=10702919.26..10702925.20 rows=48 width=13) (actual time=330574.454..330588.679 rows=63 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 8
                     Workers Launched: 8
                     ->  Sort  (cost=10701919.12..10701919.13 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=330561.376..330561.378 rows=7 loops=9)
                           Sort Key: source
                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 3:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 4:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 5:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 6:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           Worker 7:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                           ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=10701918.98..10701919.04 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=330561.260..330561.265 rows=7 loops=9)
                                 Group Key: source
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on tb_hit  (cost=0.00..10523012.32 rows=35781332 width=13) (actual time=4.019..303398.636 rows=31814705 loops=9)
```

And, after `set enable_seqscan = OFF;` this is the result of the Explain:

```
QUERY PLAN 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unique (cost=16625420.17..16625420.22 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=393693.931..393693.940 rows=7 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=16625420.17..16625420.19 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=393693.929..393693.930 rows=7 loops=1)
Sort Key: source, (count(hitid))
Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
-> Finalize GroupAggregate (cost=16625413.86..16625420.10 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=393693.825..393693.902 rows=7 loops=1)
Group Key: source
-> Gather Merge (cost=16625413.86..16625419.80 rows=48 width=13) (actual time=393693.784..395576.863 rows=63 loops=1)
Workers Planned: 8
Workers Launched: 8
-> Sort (cost=16624413.72..16624413.73 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=393680.090..393680.092 rows=7 loops=9)
Sort Key: source
Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 0: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 1: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 2: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 3: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 4: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 5: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 6: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
Worker 7: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
-> Partial HashAggregate (cost=16624413.58..16624413.64 rows=6 width=13) (actual time=393679.954..393679.959 rows=7 loops=9)
Group Key: source
-> Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on tb_hit (cost=5922341.42..16445455.86 rows=35791544 width=13) (actual time=52043.284..367453.059 rows=31814705 loops=9)
Heap Blocks: exact=1216152
-> Bitmap Index Scan on tb_hit_idx_5 (cost=0.00..5850758.33 rows=286332352 width=0) (actual time=40833.844..40833.844 rows=286332344 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.366 ms
Execution Time: 395577.824 ms
(27 rows)
```

Comment: Looks like this table would benefit a lot from partitioning by source. If not that, then reverse the order of the columns in your index. Always enumerate from low specificity to high specificity. Source, then hit id.

Answer (score 0):

First: The `DISTINCT` is superfluous here, and you should remove it. The `GROUP BY` already guarantees distinctness.

`DISTINCT` is often a performance problem, but here the case is simpler: it is the sheer number of rows that dominates the execution time.

There is no way around reading each row, and an index cannot help you here.

What you could do is to create a summary table that contains the desired result and that is updated by triggers whenever the base table is modified, so that the count is always accurate.

Then you can query that summary table, which will be very fast. The price you pay is the trigger runtime during data modification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was think in use this summary table because I will have lot of tables with big amount of data. Thanks!!!